# How to create a map for refactoring in visual mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I have the following map in IdeaVim:

```
noremap \m :action ExtractMethod<cr>
```

Which works in normal mode for a single line of code but not for visual mode (ie: when you want to refactor 3 lines of code.)

Is there any solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reopened [VIM-862](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-862) for which you voted. It appears to be a different problem not covered by [VIM-796](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-796).